# How can I fix "kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer"?

Tags: ssh, gitlab-ci, pipeline, scp, sshd

I want to copy data with `scp` in a GitLab pipeline using PRIVATE_KEY.

The error is:

```
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
Connection reset by x.x.x.x port 22
lost connection
```

Pipeline log:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.ssh

$ echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' > ~/.ssh/id_rsa

$ chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa

$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
Agent pid 22

$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Identity added: /root/.ssh/id_rsa (/root/.ssh/id_rsa)

$ ssh-keyscan -H $IP >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
# x.x.x.x:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.10
# x.x.x.x:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.10

$ scp -rv api.yml root@$IP:/home/services/test/

Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host x.x.x.x, user root, command scp -v -r -t /home/services/test/

OpenSSH_8.6p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to x.x.x.x [x.x.x.x] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.6
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
Connection reset by x.x.x.x port 22
lost connection
```

Comment: Came across this question when ssh an Asustor NAS. Check `/usr/builtin/etc/ipblock/ipblock.deny` to see if any IP is blocked. I think this is somewhat equivalent to `/etc/hosts.deny`.

Comment: Is this a newer problem (e.g., with particular versions of some software? [OpenSSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSH)?)?—Some error message at [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1463402/) (2019), [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/546394/) (2019), [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1582516/) (2020), [Nixcraft](https://www.nixcraft.com/t/kex-exchange-identification-read-connection-reset-by-peer-error-on-linux/3927) (2021), [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1413264/) (2022).

Comment: That is, is there an older canonical question? The answers don't offer *any* version information.

Comment: Is it specific to GitLab? The answers are all unspecific; it isn't specified if it was actually on GitLab or not.

Comment: A server reboot fixed it for me

Answer (score 73, accepted):

```
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

When an SSH client connects to an SSH server, the server starts by sending a version string to the client. The error that you're getting means that the TCP connection from the client to the server was "abnormally closed" while the client was waiting for this data from the server, in other words immediately after the TCP connection was opened.

As a practical matter, it's likely to mean one of two things:

1. The SSH server process malfunctioned (crashed), or perhaps it detected some serious issue causing it to exit immediately.
2. Some firewall is interfering with connections to the ssh server.

It looks like the *ssh-keyscan* program was able to connect to the server and  get a version string without an error. So the SSH server process is apparently able to talk to a client without crashing.

You should talk the administrators of this x.x.x.x host and the network that it's attached to, to see if they can identify the problem from their end. It's possible that something—a firewall, or the ssh server process itself—is seeing the multiple connections, first from the *ssh-keyscan* process, then by the *scp* program, as an intrusion attempt. And it's blocking the second connection attempt.

Comment: Your comment saved me after 1 hour of struggling to figure it out. It was the VPN that I was connected to. Now everything works fine.

Comment: Thanks for this, exactly what happened in my case. I had to reboot the server b/c it completely locked me out. That helped though.

Comment: Additionally, if the SSH error is intermittent it could be due to some limit rule reached on a firewall. Throttleling/lowering the rate of connections might make it work.

Comment: for me this was, enabling the VPN, it did the trick. I wasn't able to connect to SSH using non-VPN connection

Comment: Thanks, my issue was Avast antivirus blocking the connection.

Answer (score 29):

I had the same problem. I rebooted the server, then it was all good.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: same here after updating from ubuntu 22.04 to 22.10. all i had to do is reboot

Comment: What kind of server was that? Operating system, edition, version, etc.? Remote or local? Virtual or real hardware?

Comment: The same problem here, trying to ssh into a raspberry pi (DietPi distro). I rebooted the RPi and ssh started to work again.

Comment: Also worked on an LXC container.

Comment: how did you reboot the server? I'm getting this error while pushing my code to Gitlab

Comment: wrong address and port caused this problem for me

Comment: in my situation it was not only SSH connection problems, but also on port 80 and 81. Reboot solved problem. Before facing issues, I was tunneling connections to remote machine using other remote machine. Then I configured WiFi network on issued machine. Maybe that was the cause, that another NIC started working and another IP addr became available.

Comment: Probably the service sshd was crashed. Next time try:
sudo service sshd restart

Answer (score 10):

TL;DR: 
find the server-side process listen-to-ssh port and kill it, and then restart the *ssh* service. It should solve this problem.

On the client side:

> ```
> ssh account@ip -pPORT
> ```
>
> `kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer`

I tried it on the server side:

> ```
> service ssh status
> ```
>
> `[ ok ] sshd is running.`
>
> ```
> service ssh restart
> ```
>
> `[ ok ] Restarting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.`

but the client side ssh command still fail with the same `kex_exchange_identification` error.

Then I stop the *ssh* service on the server side (as [root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superuser)):

> ```
> service ssh stop
> ```
>
> `[ ok ] Stopping OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.`

And the following client side ssh command still fails with the same `kex_exchange_identification` error. It's strange; if no process listen the *port*, it should be the error *Connection refused*.

It could be the process on the server side listening to the SSH *port* is dead, and even a restart / stop service do not work. So to find the process, and killing it may solve the problem.

The PORT here is the SSH port defined in 'server /etc/ssh/sshd_config', and the default is 22. As root:

> ```
> netstat -ap | grep PORT
> ```
>
> `tcp   0   0 0.0.0.0:PORT   0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN 8359/sshd` 
> `tcp6  0   0 [::]:PORT      [::]:*      LISTEN 8359/sshd`
>
> ```
> kill 8359
> netstat -ap | grep PORT
> ```
>
> `no result`
>
> ```
> service ssh start
> ```
>
> `[ ok ] Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.`
>
> ```
> netstat -ap | grep PORT
> ```
>
> `tcp    0   0 0.0.0.0:PORT   0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN   31418/sshd: /usr/sb` 
> `tcp6   0   0 [::]:PORT      [::]:*      LISTEN   31418/sshd: /usr/sb`

The following client-side *ssh* command succeed.

Answer (score 4):

I met this issue after I changed my Apple ID password, so I updated my Apple ID and restarted my Mac. It works now.

```
git pull origin master
```

Output:

```
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
Connection reset by 20.205.243.166 port 22
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Restarting fixed that issue indeed.

Comment: Was it on GitLab? Or somewhere else? GitHub?

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue and resolved by:

1. Check if sshd is running on both machine.
2. Check if there exists any firewall rules which is not letting you succeed.

   iptables -L
3. check packets received while you are doing ssh using tcpdump on server:

   tcpdump -i any dst destination_IP and src Source_IP and dst port 22

output will show only 3 packets are being shared and the server closed connection.

4. check if hosts.allow is allowing only some host to make sshd connection and denying all other.

   cat /etc/hosts.allow

output may include:
sshd: IP-range subnet_range

Also, check if hosts.deny is denying some ip range to make sshd connection:

```
cat /etc/hosts.deny
```

Output may include:
**sshd: ALL**

If point 4 is your cause, then add your machine IP (from where you are trying to make ssh connection) as a hosts allowed on server machine.
Follow these steps, then, you are good to go.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to check the routing table for one possibility. In my case on [Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) (Focal Fossa), I added a local network routing entry to recover when I got the same error message when connecting to the server using SSH. It had disappeared unexpectedly, leaving only the default route.

```
route -n Kernel IP routing table Destination     Gateway
```

Output:

```
Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp1s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp1s0  # <= disappeared
```

It seemed as if *ack* was being filtered by an incomplete routing table although the first *syn* passed.

Comment: There is a similar problem with routing. The initialization of the connection went over the WAN, and the response over the LAN (Vlan)

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue whenever I was trying to connect to my Amazon Linux 2 instance through SSM or terminal:

Why did it show me the error: The */etc/hosts.deny* file specifies which IP addresses are not permitted to connect to the host. Where as I had added  "ALL: ALL" to /etc/hosts.deny and it will deny all IP address to not connect to the instance (server).

Solution: Simply you can stop the instance and edit the USER DATA and run the command

```
sed -i 's/ALL: ALL/#ALL: ALL/g' /etc/hosts.deny
```

This will comment hosts.deny. Once this is done, start the instance (server).

Answer (score 1):

Similar [to naoki-ogawa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69394001/how-can-i-fix-kex-exchange-identification-read-connection-reset-by-peer/70617508#70617508), I had a problem with my routing table. In my case, I had an extra route for my local network.

As [root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superuser):

```
route
```

Output:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         RT-AX92U-3E20   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eno1
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 virbr1
192.168.50.0    RT-AX92U-3E20   255.255.255.0   UG    10     0        0 eno1
192.168.50.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eno1
```

I simply removed the gateway on the local network (192.168.50.0):

```
route del 192.168.50.0/24 via 192.168.50.1
```

The problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

For those who came across this page after upgrading a [FreeBSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD) machine to 13.1 and then trying to ssh into it, see *[Bug 263489. sshd does not work after reboot to 13.1-RC4](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla//show_bug.cgi?id=263489)*.

After the upgrade, the previous *sshd* daemon ([OpenSSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSH) < 8.2) is still running with new configurations (OpenSSH >= 8.2).  The solution is to stop and then restart the *sshd* daemon.  The FreeBSD 13.1 release notes now mention this and after 13.1, the *freebsd-update* script will automatically restart the daemon.

Answer (score 1):

On CentOS 7.9.2009 create empty dir

```
mkdir /var/empty/sshd
chmod 0711 /var/empty/sshd
```

This helped to me

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

I had this error today when I was trying to use my Dell laptop running [Ubuntu 20.04.5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) LTS (Focal Fossa) and trying to SSH into a [Raspberry Pi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi). When I was on my *home* Wi-Fi network and tried to SSH into the pi (also on my home Wi-Fi network) I got the error:

```
ssh pi@10.0.0.200
```

Output:

```
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer'
```

However, when I switched my Ubuntu Laptop over to a mobile hotspot, the error disappeared, and I was able to SSH without issue. Will update this post as soon as I figure out how to resolve the root cause.

---

Issue resolved (but full reason unclear). I followed the [instructions to change my DNS server here](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ubuntu-dns-nameservers) to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.

After about 5 minutes had elapsed, I was able to use SSH from my command line terminal just fine.

Comment: What is the Pi running?  I get this on Ubuntu 20.04 and my Pi 3b.  My Raspbian Pi 3b devices never have this issue.  I let it cool down and try again later and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I have an Ubuntu 20.04 host and two [RHEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux) 8 VMs running on [VMware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware). I log in into the two VMs from my Ubuntu terminal. I use Ethernet and Wi-Fi connections. Every time I tried to log into a VM after rebooting it, I would get the error:

```
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
Connection reset by x.x.x.x port 22
```

Restarting the *sshd* service would not solve the problem. Sometimes, the problem would be resolved if I physically disconnected and reconnected the Ethernet cable.

Finally I turned off my Wi-Fi connection with:

```
nmcli conn down <name_of_Wi-Fi_connection>
```

Or turning it off from settings and this gave me a permanent solution.

Both my Ethernet and Wi-Fi connections (static connections) had the same IP address, so I think the VMs were rejecting two "suspicious" similar connections.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75300947/edit) (it covers ***answers, program input, and program output*** as well). Thanks in advance.

Comment: What name? The [SSID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi#Etymology_and_terminology)? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was with a Synology server, the private IP accidentally went into the DSM's block list.
Removing it and putting the whole subnet on the allow list fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change my DNS, I used **[shecan.ir](https://shecan.ir)**
If you are from Iran, you most probably have the same issue, particularly when using gitlab.com

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should change the resolution of host

Press win+R, enter C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc to open the location of the host file:
[image]

add [IP] : Domain name    for example   1.1.1.1  google

Answer (score -2):

The same issue with me:

I have fixed the issue by doing the below steps.

1. edit file *etc/hosts.allow*. Command to do so *sudo nano /etc/hosts.allow*.
2. At the end, update the value of <kbd>ALL</kbd> keys to `ALL` like `ALL : ALL`. Save the file and try again.

Basically, `ALL` might be set to something else therefore while establishing ssh connection to the host, it is expecting that the request should come from the IP address starting from 10.*.*.* if ALL set to `ALL : 10.`. Therefore by replacing 10. with ALL, you are allowing connection from everywhere.

Answer (score -2):

Try to check if [OpenSSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSH) server is up and running on the server side.

Try checking the *sshd* configuration. It worked this way for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is a very simplistic answer and rather unhelpful.